# Wierd Black things in solid view Blender 2.91.2

Tags: 3d-view

I just opened the project file from blender cloud (Rain v2) and this happened.

I tried to fix it for an hour, but I found nothing similar. I have an RX 580 and a Ryzen 5 1400 with the recommended drivers.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that this could be yet another issue with AMD cards. See this related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210864/alpha-transparency-glitching-viewport-display-amd